# How to make caret visible in GeckoFX control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, geckofx, html-editor

I am making a WYSIWYG HTML-editor by embedding GeckoFX in a Windows Forms application in VB.NET.
This is the code:

```
Imports Gecko
...
Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("C:\Program Files (x86)\XULrunner-33.0")
...
Dim gBrowser As New GeckoWebBrowser
TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(gBrowser)
gBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
gBrowser.Navigate("about:blank")
```

This is how I make Web page editable:

```
gBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(document.body.contentEditable='true')")
```

But after I make the page editable, the caret does not show up until I click the page.
How can I make caret visible at an insertion point right after the Navigate method?
This code has no visible effect:

```
gBrowser.SetInputFocus()
Dim fm As nsIFocusManager
fm = Xpcom.GetService(Of nsIFocusManager)("@mozilla.org/focus-manager;1")
fm = Xpcom.QueryInterface(Of nsIFocusManager)(fm)
fm.MoveCaretToFocus(gBrowser.Window.DomWindow)
```

Thank you.

Comment: It maybe that the window is active but the body element doesn't have focus. I would try getting the body element and calling focus on it.

Comment: Hi, Tom. Thanks for the suggestion. Alas, this code does not have any effect either: gBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).Focus()

Comment: Does the actual winforms control have focus (IE. the GeckoWebBrowerControl) - if not you could try gBrowser.Select(). In Addition another thing to call is gBrowser.WebBrowserFocus.Activate();

Comment: Thank you, Tom. Both of your suggestions worked! Either gBrowser.Select() or gBrowser.WebBrowserFocus.Activate() together with gBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).Focus() do the trick. Would you care to write an answer, so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an embedded geckofx control in a winforms application it's important to remember that there are two focus in play.

In order to set the winform focus on the geckofx control:

```
gBrowser.Select();
```

In order to set the html focus inside the geckofx control call focus on a html element. for example (where Body is a content editable element):

```
gBrowser.Document.Body.Focus();
```